# Scrapy rule deny

Tags: scrapy

How can I deny scraping of certain parts of a website by using Rules in Scrapy.

I want Scrapy to crawl links mathcing www.example.com/help/nl/ en deny all links matching www.example.com/help/en/ and www.example.com/website/.

I have the following code:

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'myspider'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com', ]
    start_urls = ['https://www.example.com/help/nl/', ]
    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'/help/nl/',)), callback='parse_response'),
    )
```

But it is crawling the entire website.

**UPDATE**

I want Scrapy to follow ONLY links containing /help/nl/

```
Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'/help/nl/',), deny=(other than /help/nl/), callback='parse_response')
```

Comment: What URL/website are you crawling?

Comment: https://online.milieubarometer.nl/help/nl/

Comment: What's the value of `downloader/response_count` when you run the crawler (it'll be shown at the end of the log), and could you edit the question to show some of the crawled pages that you'd like to exclude? I just ran the code with your rule and akhter's rule, and the same number of pages were crawled, and all were of the form "./help/nl/".

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'myspider'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com', ]
    start_urls = ['https://www.example.com/help/nl/', ]
    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'/help/nl/',),deny=(r'/en/$',r'/website/$',)), callback='parse_response'),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

My resolve was very similar to @akhter answer. However I didnt use regex.

I used:

```
deny=('/help', '/website')
```

It should make it so that it blocks anything that has that in the url (/help or /website)

Hope it helps